# Error"Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided"

Tags: java, jquery, file, spring-mvc

I have a problem when i try to use fileupload to upload image file in java i use ajax to upload image. but when I run it, it gives an error: "Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided" please help me

this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dothanh</groupId>
  <artifactId>shophai</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>project name</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is my servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">


         <context:component-scan base-package="com.dothanh.Controller"></context:component-scan>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
    
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
  </bean>

</beans>
```

this is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var files =[];
    $("#productPhotos").change(function(event){
        files = event.target.files;
        forms = new FormData();
        forms.append("file",files[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "/shophai/api/uploadfile",
            type: "POST",
            data:forms ,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            enctype:"multipart/form-data",
            success: function (value) { 
            }
        })
    });
});
```

this is my APIController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class APIController {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;
    
    @PostMapping("uploadfile")
    @ResponseBody
    public String UpLoadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
        String PathToProducts = servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/Image/");
        Iterator<String> imageName = request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile imageFile =request.getFile(imageName.next());
        
        File fileSave = new File(PathToProducts + imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            imageFile.transferTo(fileSave);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(PathToProducts);
        
        return"";
    }


}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue after upgrading to Spring Boot 3